# SalesforceIQ/RelateIQ API: how do I create a contact for external users (OAuth?)

Tags: oauth, salesforce

I'm building an app that shows users people they might be interested in talking to. If a user says he's interested in a person I show them, I want my app to create this person as a contact in my user's SalesforceIQ.

How do I do this? I see from the API documentation https://api.salesforceiq.com/#/ruby#documentation_contacts_create-a-contact that I can create a contact if I know my user's username and password, but of course I don't want my users to give me this information. Is there some way for the user to OAuth or whatnot by clicking a button that authorizes me to add things to their SalesforceIQ?

Answer (score 0):

The SalesforceIQ API uses HTTP Basic authentication and does not currently support OAuth [according to their documentation](https://api.salesforceiq.com/#/curl#documentation_introduction-and-basics_security-and-authentication_basic-authentication).

For a SalesforceIQ user to grant API access to your app to create contacts and for other privileges, the SalesforceIQ admin creates an API Key and API Secret for your app which is then used for the HTTP Basic authentication username and password. This way no user needs to provide your app with their credentials. This is configured in the SalesforceIQ admin UI under `Settings` > `Integrations` > `Create New Custom Integration`.

For the admin to provide these credentials to your app, you can have a UI where the SalesforceIQ admin enters this for your app to store and use with the API for their account.

This is described in the following places, briefly in the API Reference and in detail in a Help Desk article with screenshots of what the SalesforceIQ admin needs to do:

1. [API Reference: Requesting Access](https://api.salesforceiq.com/#/curl#documentation_introduction-and-basics_requesting-access)
2. [API Reference: Security and Authentication](https://api.salesforceiq.com/#/curl#documentation_introduction-and-basics_security-and-authentication_basic-authentication)
3. [Help Article: Set up API access](https://help.salesforceiq.com/articles/set-up-api-access)